# React Native - Floating (or popup) Screen question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, user-experience

I'm trying to do something like that last image, the one that has the product detail to add to cart with the blurred background

Is there a way to make that floating screen in react navite?

I'm looking for something maybe similar to it, I don't really care about the content inside of it, just the general screen popup

I dont know how its called, so pointing me in a direction to do research or just naming it so I can google it would very much be appreciated it

[image: https://imgur.com/a/u3EFMvs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called Modal and you can use React Native's component to present it. Check for official documentation https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal

For the blur part, you can use this library https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-blur

Here is a sample code to show the modal:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Alert, Modal, StyleSheet, Text, Pressable, View } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
              onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <Pressable
        style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOpen]}
        onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}
      >
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Show Modal</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 22
  },
  modalView: {
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 10,
    elevation: 2
  },
  buttonOpen: {
    backgroundColor: "#F194FF",
  },
  buttonClose: {
    backgroundColor: "#2196F3",
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  modalText: {
    marginBottom: 15,
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});

export default App;
```